# Pass php variabe to modal

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter-3

In this modal bootstrap window I would like to pass php variables that are displayed in a table.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
<h4 style="text-align:center;color:green">Bienvedio $var1 var2 </h4>
</div>
```

The table containing the data displayed

```
 <?php foreach($EMPLOYEES as $employee){?>
 <tr>
 <td><?=$employee->id_acd;?></td>
 <td><?=$employee->nombre;?></td>
 <td> <a data-toggle="modal" href="<?php echo site_url("navigation/description/".$employee->id_acd); ?>#myModal" class="btn btn-warning">
  <span class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a></td>
 </tr>     
    <?php }?>
```

When I click on the link the modal window is displayed but I do not know how to pass the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you need to pass them with javascript;

```
<table>
<tr>
 <td class="dataId">213</td>
 <td class="name">John Snow</td>
 <td> <a class="copyToModal" data-toggle="modal" href="#do">Copy data</a> 
 </tr>
 </table>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
<form id="userText" method="post">
<input type="text"  name="id_acd" id="id_acd" >
<input type="text"  name="nombre" id="nombre" >
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

and javascript code:

```
$(".copyToModal").click(function (){
    var id_acd= $(this).closest("tr").find(".id_acd").text();
    var nombre= $(this).closest("tr").find(".nombre").text();

     $('#id_acd').val(id_acd);
    $('#nombre').val(nombre);
    })
```

Full example : https://jsfiddle.net/vt88p9k8/9/

Comment: thank you for your response but i wish your code would be more completed to grab the idea.

Comment: I edited my answer. Check jsfidle  (click there run and click "Copy data" button). Is that answer your question?

Comment: thank you so much it works, but i would like to retreive each variable in

Comment: Thank you so much it works i vote you up, but i would like to retreive each variable in input value of a form. The form is found in the modal.

Comment: Ok i success to pass variables in a form. I edit your codes. You save my life.

Comment: i jsut did it. Cool. Can you remove my down vote question ?

Answer (score 0):

To load data remotely  add `data-remote="http://example.com"` attribute to modal main element:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" data-remote="http://example.com/load.php">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <h4 style="text-align:center;color:green">Bienvedio $var1 var2 </h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i use codeigniter.  After load the data remotely how can i display according the value kept in the link  ?